# How to look up from two values of data frame and map them - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, lookup

I have two pandas dataframe, name `df1`, and `df2`. `df1` looks like below:

```
df1=
tagx tagy datetime
302.  303. 2020-07-01 12:22:31
402.  811. 2020-07-01 12:20:33
.
.
.
.
```

and `df2` is like below:

```
df2=
Latitude. Longitude.  datetime                  tag
5.01.      52.0988.   2020-07-01 12:22:31       302
5.01.      52.0233.   2020-07-01 12:22:31       303
5.02.      52.0888.   2020-07-01 12:20:33       402
5.02.      52.0122.   2020-07-01 12:20:33       811
.
.
.
```

I want to look into the `df1` and find the value of `df1['tagx', 'datetime']`, in `df2` as `df2['tag', 'datetime']`, then if I could find, take the Latitude and Longitude to the `df1` and add as `LatitudeX` and `LongitudeX` on `df1[tagx, datetime]` rows.(Then repeat the same for `tagY`)

This is what I like to have:

```
df1=
tagx tagy datetime              LatitudeX  LongitudeX     LatitudeY LongitudeY        
302.  303. 2020-07-01 12:22:31.  5.01.      52.0988.      5.01.      52.0233.
402.  811. 2020-07-01 12:20:33.  5.02.      52.0888.      5.02.      52.0122.
.
.
.
```

Note that in `df2`, datetime cannot be indexed as it doesn't have unique values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what's failed?

Comment: First, I've tried to do by map, it failed because it only looks into one column, not two columns at same time and also it needs to look up based on index, while in df2 the unique value as index is having both datetime and tag together. None of them is unique alone.

Comment: Second, I've tried to do this by merge. According to documents it should work by merge, but for me it can only look into one of the columns and decide, not both.

Comment: @maedenasri Are the `.` in the column names in `df2` intentional or its just a typo?

Comment: Its part of the name, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
left = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['tagx', 'datetime'], right_on=['tag', 'datetime'])\
    .rename(columns={'Latitude.': 'LatitudeX', 'Longitude.': 'LongitudeX'})\
    .drop(columns='tag')

right = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['tagy', 'datetime'], right_on=['tag', 'datetime'])\
    .rename(columns={'Latitude.': 'LatitudeY', 'Longitude.': 'LongitudeY'})\
    .drop(columns='tag')

print(pd.merge(left, right, on=['tagx', 'tagy', 'datetime']))
```

Output

```
    tagx   tagy             datetime LatitudeX LongitudeX LatitudeY LongitudeY
0  302.0  303.0  2020-07-01 12:22:31     5.01.   52.0988.     5.01.   52.0233.
1  402.0  811.0  2020-07-01 12:20:33     5.02.   52.0888.     5.02.   52.0122.
```